# Как правильно: выучившем или выучившим?

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение

Как будет правильно (о человеке):

*выучивш**ем*** или *выучивш**им***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: **о человеке (какОМ?) выучившЕМ.**

Проверочный вопрос дает нам окончание **ОМ/ЕМ**, после мягких и шипящих согласных выбираем вариант **ЕМ**.

Сравнить: он был **человеком (какИМ?) выучившИМ,** окончание **ИМ**.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от предложения.
Если "О ком, о каком?", то ***выучившем**.
Если "Кем, каким?", то ***выучившим**

Например.
*Мы поговорили о человеке (каком?), выучившем таблицу умножения.

Мы знакомы с человеком (каким?), выучившим таблицу умножения.*